# jQuery dialog box wont stay, vanishes after a second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to stick an "Add" button to my generated form which will pop up a dialogue which eventually will have a form in it (right now it just says "I am a dialogue"). The form is generated by my GetJSON callback *(the form just contains a select list, I want to be able to "Add" a new member, or "Edit" the current selection from that select list with a nice pop up window)*.

For some reason it vanishes after a second or so. The page is then regenerated, that's OK actually as my DB might have an extra record in it after the dialogue so I dont mind that, but I need the dialogue to hang about obviously.

Is this to do with getJSON() being asynchronous ?.

Here is my javascript, and below that is the html. I had some issues with the wrong jquery-ui.js trying to get pop up dialogues to work at all, so may be I still have the wrong version of the *stuff*. But I can get the simple version of the demo site to work OK which is why I am now suspicious of getJSON.

```
function getTable(tableName,keyName,displayField,matchField,matchValue){
    $url= "/GeeREST/Entity?entity="+tableName+"&order="+displayField;

    if (matchField != null){
        $url+="&field="+matchField+"&value="+matchValue;
    }

    $.getJSON($url, 
            function( data ) {
            var items = [];
            $("#form-"+tableName).remove();
            $("#select-"+tableName).remove();
            $("<form>",{id:"form-"+tableName}).appendTo("#"+tableName);

            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                items.push("<option value=\"" + val[keyName]+"\">"+val[displayField]+"</option>");
            });
            $("<select/>", {
                id: "select-"+tableName,
                name: "select-"+tableName,
                html: items.join( "" )
                }).appendTo("#form-"+tableName);
            $("<button>",{
                id:"opener-"+tableName,
                html:"Add"
                }).appendTo("#form-"+tableName);
            $( "#dialog-"+tableName ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
            $( "#opener-"+tableName ).click(function() {
                $( "#dialog-"+tableName ).dialog( "open" );
            });

            addChangeFunction(tableName);
            configureSubSelects(tableName);
        });

}

function SetUp(){
    getTable("Agency","agencyId","agencyName");
    getTable("Routes","routeId","routeId");
    getTable("Stops","stopId","stopName");
    getTable("Calendar","calendarId","serviceId");
//  getTable("Trips","tripId","tripId");
//  getTable("StopTimes","stopId","stopId");
}

function addChangeFunction(tableName){
    switch (tableName){
        case 'Routes': 
            $('#select-Routes').change(function() {
                configureSubSelects('Routes');
            });
        break;
        case 'Trips': 
            $('#select-Trips').change(function() {
                configureSubSelects('Trips');
            });
        break;
    }
}

function configureSubSelects(tableName){
    switch (tableName){
        case 'Routes': 
            getTable("Trips","tripId","tripId","routeId",$('#select-Routes').val());
        break;

        case 'Trips': 
            getTable("StopTimes","stopId","stopId","tripId",$('#select-Trips').val());
        break;
    }
}
```

And here's my HTML. I've only put in the first dialog(ue) in for "Agency"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Editor.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<title>Welcome to Gee</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog-Agency" title="Add Agency">I'm an add agency dialogue</div>

<script>
SetUp();
</script>

<div id="Agency">
Agencies
</div>
<div id="Routes">
Routes
</div>
<div id="Stops">
Stops
</div>
<div id="Calendar">
Calendar
</div>
<hr>
<div id="Trips">
Trips
</div>
<div id="StopTimes">
Stop Times
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tied the dialog open event to the click action of a button in your form. The default action of a button element is to submit the form, so what seems to be happening is that when you click the button to open the dialog, you're also submitting the form and the page reloads. To prevent that, try adding `.preventDefault()` to your click event handler:

```
$( "#opener-"+tableName ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( "#dialog-"+tableName ).dialog( "open" );
});
```